# Yocto Linux for Banan Pi?

Tags: linux, yocto, banana-pi, mender

I would like to use mender.io for OTA software updates for my Banana PI. Mender.io uses yocto linux and i am totally new to yocto linux. There are some examples and tutorial for Raspberry PI on the internet but i havent found any tutorial for Banana PI. Now, how much banana PI is different then raspberry PI? And e.g. i have the yocto environment setup for the Raspberry PI, what changes do i need to do in that environment to use it for Banana PI? what is the best starting point to start using yocto for Banana PI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`meta-sunxi`](https://github.com/linux-sunxi/meta-sunxi) seems to carry support for the bananapi, thats already a good start.

Technically, you have to

1. set up a build
2. add the `meta-sunxi` layer
3. set `MACHINE` to bananapi
4. build.

Please be aware that the Yocto mindset is massively different from a conventional general purpose distro, as its all about image creation and does not offer online package repositories. So before actually investing much time, have a look at our introductory [live coding sessions](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD4M5FoHz-TxMfBFrDKfIS_GLY25Qsfyj) to get an idea if it actually suits your needs.

Comment: Danke @Leto.. i have one more question that e.g. meta-sunxi doesnt have a bananapi gpio recipe. in that case i have to develop my own recipe for it?or can i also use recipes from raspberrypi layers? Thanks

Comment: @HassanHaroon no idea, I've never used either of them. Generally its like this: you can use things from all layers, mix and match as needed. If what you need comes from a source package that has no recipe yet, then you have to write a recipe. But if what you need is already in `meta-raspberrypi`, then you can totally jsut add both layers and use the bits and pieces you need from the raspi and build for another machine.

Comment: so thats mean recipes are not machine independent? so we can use any recipe e.g.  written for one machine in another machine? or i understood it wrong? :-|

Comment: recipes are machine independent if the source they use is machine independent, and the recipe has been written accordingly. but of course a recipe that brings something that is hw-dependent, like a specific driver or such, then they are machine dependent. so, its really up to the specific recipe in question.